# Routing when passing data in URL

Tags: zend-framework2

I have created a basic Zend Framework 2 application using the Skeleton Application and Module although I have encountered a routing problem and can't seem to work around it.

Within my module, which is loosely based on the new Quickstart module on the Zend Framework web site, I have the following route within module.config.php

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'blog' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                // Change this to something specific to your module
                'route'    => '/blog',
                'defaults' => array(
                    // Change this value to reflect the namespace in which
                    // the controllers for your module are found
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Blog\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'View',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                // This route is a sane default when developing a module;
                // as you solidify the routes for your module, however,
                // you may want to remove it and replace it with more
                // specific routes.
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '[/:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

This route appears to work fine when using a standard module, controller and action URL request:

```
blah.com/blog/post/view
```

Where I am having problems is when I try to pass some data over the URL:

```
blah.com/blog/post/view/id/1
```

The latter of the two URLs results in a 404. I am guessing I need a child route to allow for data to be passed on the URL, although I am stuck on exactly what I would need. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction? I have browsed the reference guide, although I can't seem to get across the line.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add optional segments to your route. Also add default values for it: try this:

```
'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '[/:controller[/:action[/id[/:idvar]]]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'idvar'  => '0'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
```

and within your controller action, try:

`$id = $this->params('idvar')`;

to retrieve the `idvar` value.

Answer (score 2):

In case you need multiple parameters which are optional and can be provided in any random combination (e.g. pageNumber = 2, participation = active), you need to add a child route of type query and with this you can provide GET parameters completely flexible:

The url fitting the following example can be build with the url view helper using this syntay:
$this->url('event/index/query', array('o_id' => 1, 'participation' => 'active','pageNumber' => '2'));

```
    'routes' => array(
       'event' => array(
            'type'    => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/event',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'cebEvent.eventController',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'index' => array(
                    'type' => 'segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/index[/:o_id]',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'eventController',
                            'action'     => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                    'child_routes' => array(
                        'query' => array(
                            'type' => 'Query',
                        ),
                    ),

                ),
```